# Bit-wise AND in C language

Tags: c, decimal, octal

Consider the following statement given in C book by Dennis ritchie

> The bitwise AND operator & is often used to mask off some set of bits,
>
> for example
>
> ```
> n = n & 0177;
> ```
>
> sets to zero all but the low-order 7 bits of `n`.

Regarding bit-wise AND operator, my understanding is as follows

11010010 & 01101010 = 01000010

i.e., sets to 0 if the corresponding bit in any operand is 0

But in the above quoted statement, it is told that the the bits are 0 except the last 7.

If we expand 0177 in binary, it will be 10110001 (8-bits), so we cannot say about lower order 8 bits. Where i went wrong?

Comment: `0177` is **octal** value hex `0x7F`. Now you can see why the least 7 bits are mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.4.1, (*emphasis mine*)

> [...] An octal constant **consists of the prefix `0`** optionally followed by a sequence of the
>   **digits `0` through `7` only**. [...]

So, an **integer constant** like `0177` is octal, which is the same as decimal `127` or hex `7F`. The binary representation gives you `01111111`, which is the true in

> *[...] sets to zero all but the low-order 7 bits of `n`.*

Answer (score 4):

You converted the mask to 177 as if it were decimal. However, it is not so: leading zero makes it an octal constant.

Therefore, its binary representation is

```
01111111
```

As you can see, it masks off all bits except the lower 7.

In the old days, octal notation has been popular with programmers of PDP computers, because it let them "read" binary code more easily. It is much less popular now, with hex notation mostly taking its place when defining binary masks.

Comment: Does C language consider any number starting with 0 as octal?

Comment: `0x7F` is hexadecimal.

Comment: @WeatherVane that's why I stick to _quotes_ :)

Comment: @hanugm leading zero w/no "x" indicates octal.

Comment: @hanugm : Yes it does, including `0` itself - although that is the same in decimal so you don't notice.  Note also that it can be used in character constants so while `'\0'` is used for NUL, `'\0177'` and `'\x7f'` are both character 127 (DEL in ASCII).

Answer (score 3):

In C integers prefixed 0 are octal (base 8) so 0177 = 001 111 111<sub>2</sub>.

In octal, each digit 0-7 represents exactly 3 binary digits.  It is somewhat arcane and archaic, a hangover from the days when word-lengths of 12 bits for example were not uncommon (PDP8 for example).  It is an unfortunate representation, as it catches out the unwary rather more frequently than it is any longer useful as a numeric notation.

My advice when writing bit-fields is to stick to hexadecimal (`0x7f` in this case) where each digit represents 4 binary digits so fits in with *multiple-of-eight* word lengths on modern architectures.

Another gotcha occurs incidentally if you use the `%i` format specifier for input - that too interprets `0` and `0x` prefixes as octal and hex respectively, which can lead to confusing errors if the data source generated leading decimal zeroes.